# How to write a query from string with logical operator in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2019

I have a string that may contain logical operator (just `AND`, `OR`) in it, I pass it to a stored procedure in SQL Server 2019 to search multiple phrase in one column of a table.

```
"Hello mary AND job for OR dentist"
```

I want to build such a query with a `where` clause:

```
where (Text like N'%Hello mary%' and Text like N'%job for%') 
   or Text like N'%dentist%'
```

What is the best solution to split it and make that query?

Edit:

Actually in my application I have 3 textboxes (A, B, C) that users can enter 3 phrases into them and between them I have a radio button (op) that shows `And` or `Or` operator, And I want to make query `(A op B) op C`

Comment: This feels like an XY Problem, if am honest. Though, if you *had* to do something like this I would recommend against passing a sentence and instead use a table type parameter.

Comment: In your example, which portion of the predicate will be fed with the parameter? the `and` or the `or`?

Comment: how do you know it should not be Text like N'%Hello mary%' And (Text like N'%job for%' OR Text like N'%dentist%')

Comment: There is no "best" solution since that depends on too many factors to address in a public forum like this. I suggest that you may have over-simplified the complexity you will need to accommodate - and as already noted you make assumptions about precedence about and/or.

Comment: @SMor I updated my question, if you have a solution or suggestion

Comment: @The Impaler I updated my question

Comment: Well that changed things. Seems like a **parmetrised**  dyamic statement might be what you are after. Of course, we still have no idea where/if parentheses are needed.

Comment: @Larnu I myself decided to set parentheses where I want, could you please explain more what should I do?

Comment: I think we need several examples here. We don't have enough information and I'm not guessing and getting wrong (and being expected to address moving goal posts).

Comment: Which language are you using in the application? C#?

Comment: Not understanding why your string contains the logical operators if the user selects them using radio buttons, you just need to send the text box values and the separate operator values, no need to combine everything into a single string and then have to parse them out again.